# How to delete untagged images from AWS ECR Container Registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

When pushing images to Amazon ECR, if the tag already exists within the repo the old image remains within the registry but goes in an untagged state.

So if i docker push `image/haha:1.0.0` the second time i do this (provided that something changes) the first image gets untagged from `AWS ECR`.

Is there a way to safely clean up all the registries from untagged images?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I actually forged a one line solution using `aws cli`

```
aws ecr describe-repositories --output text | awk '{print $5}' | egrep -v '^$' | while read line; do  repo=$(echo $line | sed -e  "s/arn:aws:ecr.*\///g") ; aws ecr list-images --repository-name $repo --filter tagStatus=UNTAGGED --query 'imageIds[*]' --output text | while read imageId; do aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name $repo --image-ids imageDigest=$imageId; done; done
```

What it's doing is:

- get all repositories
- for each repository give me all images with `tagStatus=UNTAGGED`
- for each image+repo issue a `batch-delete-image`

If you have [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you can use this version that is more robust by not relying on the changing text format and also more efficient as it batch deletes once per repository:

```
aws ecr  describe-repositories \
| jq --raw-output .repositories[].repositoryName \
| while read repo; do  
    imageIds=$(aws ecr list-images --repository-name $repo --filter tagStatus=UNTAGGED --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json  | jq -r '[.[].imageDigest] | map("imageDigest="+.) | join (" ")');
    if [[ "$imageIds" == "" ]]; then continue; fi
    aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name $repo --image-ids $imageIds; 
done
```

This has been broken up into more lines for readability, so better [put it into a function in your .bashrc](https://github.com/fatso83/dotfiles/commit/11160f7f2f4930ee26209580189969a723663b89), but you could of course stuff it into a single line:

```
aws ecr  describe-repositories | jq --raw-output .repositories[].repositoryName | while read repo; do           imageIds=$(aws ecr list-images --repository-name $repo --filter tagStatus=UNTAGGED --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json  | jq -r '[.[].imageDigest] | map("imageDigest="+.) | join (" ")');         if [[ "$imageIds" == "" ]]; then continue; fi;         aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name $repo --image-ids $imageIds;      done
```

Comment: Could be that the AWS CLI output changed, but `awk '{print $5}'` gives the ARN. It should be `awk '{print $6}'` to get the repository name.

Comment: The original answer no longer works, as the output does not match. I'll update.

Answer (score 54):

You can delete all images in a single request, without loops:

```
IMAGES_TO_DELETE=$( aws ecr list-images --region $ECR_REGION --repository-name $ECR_REPO --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --output json )

aws ecr batch-delete-image --region $ECR_REGION --repository-name $ECR_REPO --image-ids "$IMAGES_TO_DELETE" || true
```

First it gets a list of images that are untagged, in json format:

`[ {"imageDigest": "sha256:..."}, {"imageDigest": "sha256:..."}, ... ]`

Then it sends that list to `batch-image-delete`.

The last `|| true` is required to avoid an error code when there are no untagged images.

Comment: I don't have the '--filter' option, what version do you use? (I have aws-cli/1.10.39)

Comment: Update: v1.11.44 supports filters

Comment: ECR doesn't support more than 100 images. This fixes that:
```
IMAGES_TO_DELETE=$( aws ecr list-images --region $ECR_REGION --repository-name $ECR_REPO --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[*]' --max-items 100 --output json )
aws ecr batch-delete-image --region $ECR_REGION --repository-name $ECR_REPO --image-ids "$IMAGES_TO_DELETE" || true
```

Comment: `aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name $name --image-ids "$(aws ecr list-images --query 'imageIds[*]' --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --max-items 100 --repository-name $name)"`

Answer (score 44):

Now, that ECR support lifecycle policies (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/LifecyclePolicies.html) you can use it to delete the untagged images automatically.

> Setting up a lifecycle policy preview using the console
>
> Open the Amazon ECS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/.
>
> From the navigation bar, choose the region that contains the
>   repository on which to perform a lifecycle policy preview.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Repositories and select a repository.
>
> On the All repositories: repository_name page, choose Dry-Run
>   Lifecycle Rules, Add.
>
> Enter the following details for your lifecycle policy rule:
>
> For Rule Priority, type a number for the rule priority.
>
> For Rule Description, type a description for the lifecycle policy
>   rule.
>
> For Image Status, choose either Tagged or Untagged.
>
> If you specified Tagged for Image Status, then for Tag Prefix List,
>   you can optionally specify a list of image tags on which to take
>   action with your lifecycle policy. If you specified Untagged, this
>   field must be empty.
>
> For Match criteria, choose values for Count Type, Count Number, and
>   Count Unit (if applicable).
>
> Choose Save
>
> Create additional lifecycle policy rules by repeating steps 5–7.
>
> To run the lifecycle policy preview, choose Save and preview results.
>
> Under Preview Image Results, review the impact of your lifecycle
>   policy preview.
>
> If you are satisfied with the preview results, choose Apply as
>   lifecycle policy to create a lifecycle policy with the specified
>   rules.

From here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/lpp_creation.html

Comment: I tried the steps listed in your answer, but it doesn't seem to delete old images. When dry-running the policy it correctly lists all images I intend to delete, but they don't actually get deleted when applying the policy. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: @Broadwell ... it doesn't run immediately after applying the policy.  Give it some time (an hour to two) and you'll find that it runs.

Answer (score 7):

Setting a Lifecycle policy is definitely the best way of managing this. That being said - if you do have a bunch of images that you want to delete keep in mind that the max for batch-delete-images is 100. So you need to do this is for the number of untagged images is greater than 100:

```
IMAGES_TO_DELETE=$( aws ecr list-images --repository-name $ECR_REPO --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'imageIds[0:100]' --output json )
echo $IMAGES_TO_DELETE | jq length # Gets the number of results
aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name $ECR_REPO --image-ids "$IMAGES_TO_DELETE" --profile qa || true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an untagged image from a repository you can simply create a JSON lifecycle policy and then use python to apply the JSON policy to the repo

In my case, I  am applying the policy to all the ECR repositories that are there in ECR and I have created a "lifecyclepolicy.json" file in my current directory where I have added the lifecycle policy of ECR

**Here is my python code:-**

```py
    import os
    import json
    import boto3
 
    def ecr_lifecycle(lifecycle_policy):
        ecr_client = boto3.client('ecr')

        repositories = []
        describe_repo_paginator = ecr_client.get_paginator('describe_repositories')
        for response_list_repopaginator in describe_repo_paginator.paginate():
            for repo in response_list_repopaginator['repositories']:
                repositories.append(repo['repositoryName'])
        for repository in repositories:
            response=ecr_client.put_lifecycle_policy(repositoryName=repository,
            lifecyclePolicyText=json.dumps(lifecycle_policy))
        return response


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        path = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
        json_file = open(os.path.join(path, 'lifecyclepolicy.json'))
        data = json.load(json_file)
        ecr_lifecycle(data)
```

**If you want to see the JSON file:-**

```
{

"rules": [
    {
      {
        "rulePriority": 10,
        "description": "Only keep untagged images for 7 days",
        "selection": {
            "tagStatus": "untagged",
            "countType": "sinceImagePushed",
            "countUnit": "days",
            "countNumber": 7
        }
        "action": {
            "type": "expire"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on @Ken J's anwer,

Here is a python script that will clean ALL your ECR:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
import json
import os
# Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949342/how-to-delete-untagged-images-from-aws-ecr-container-registry
region="us-east-1"

debug = False

def _runCommand(command):
    if debug:
        print(" ".join(command))
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = False, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    return [p.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"), p.stderr.read().decode("utf-8")]

command = "aws ecr describe-repositories --region " + region + " --output json".split(" ")
data = _runCommand(command)[0]

for i in json.loads(data)["repositories"]:
     name = i["repositoryName"]
     print(name)
     command = ["aws", "ecr", "list-images", "--region", region, "--repository-name", name, "--filter", "tagStatus=UNTAGGED", "--query", 'imageIds[*]', "--output" , "json"]
     data = _runCommand(command)[0]
     
     command = ["aws", "ecr", "batch-delete-image", "--region", region, "--repository-name", name, "--image-ids",data]
     data = _runCommand(command)[0]
     print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### First Step -->

```
untaggedImages = aws ecr list-images --repository-name <your_repo_name> --filter "tagStatus=UNTAGGED" --query 'to_string(imageIds[*])' --output json""")
```

##### Second step -->

```
aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name <your_repo_name> --image-ids "$untaggedImages" || true """)
```

> **to_string function is required because the returned JSON won't be in string format, instead it will be as an Object.**