# How to delete untagged images in ECR

Tags: docker, aws-ecr

After pushing docker image(with `test` tag) to ECR, more than one time, older docker images goes untagged in ECR

What is the AWS CLI command to delete untagged image in ECR?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete untagged images from AWS ECR Container Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949342/how-to-delete-untagged-images-from-aws-ecr-container-registry)

Comment: @LinPy Not really working... Untagged image has image URI:  `1111222334455.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/someimage@sha256:feeeeeeeee00d1e0b18fa5a19d15c3cb47d222e345862ddddddddddd0`......  What is `ECR_REPO` from this URI? I set it as `someimage`, which does not work

Answer (score 3):

You can use ECR lifecycle policy, which has been recently added by AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/LifecyclePolicies.html

Here's an example of a policy to only keep one untagged image and expire all others [image: ECR policy rule]

Answer (score 2):

You can try using aws cli - set the correct AWS REGION where your ecr repositories exists.

```
AWSREGION=us-west-2 && ecr describe-repositories --region=$AWSREGION --output text | awk '$5{print $5}' | sed -n  's/.*repository\/\(.*\)/\1/p' | while read line; do aws ecr list-images --region=$AWSREGION --repository-name "$line" --filter tagStatus=UNTAGGED --query 'imageIds[*]' --output text | while read imageId; do aws ecr batch-delete-image  --region=$AWSREGION --repository-name "$line" --image-ids imageDigest=$imageId; done; done
```

This command will delete all the untagged images recursively. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: To delete any image (untagged or tagged) "AWSREGION=us-east-1 && aws ecr describe-repositories --region=$AWSREGION --output text | awk '$5{print $5}' | sed -n 's/.*repository\/(.*)/\1/p' | while read line; do aws ecr list-images --region=$AWSREGION --repository-name "$line" --filter tagStatus=ANY --query 'imageIds[*]' --output text | awk '$1{print $1}' |while read imageId; do aws ecr batch-delete-image --region=$AWSREGION --repository-name "$line" --image-ids imageDigest=$imageId; done; done"

Answer (score 1):

What happens is when you publish an `image:tag` the tag will be removed from the previous image.

You can run a CLI command to identify the images that are untagged and pipe the output to the command to delete those.

You can also use lifecycle policies.

Refer the link below. I haven't tested this myself.

reference:
[How to delete untagged images from AWS ECR Container Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949342/how-to-delete-untagged-images-from-aws-ecr-container-registry)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/LifecyclePolicies.html

Comment: What does `ECR_REPO` mean? Because I see untagged image URI in ECR as: `1111222334455.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/someimage@sha256:feeeeeeeee00d1e0b18fa5a19d15c3cb47d222e345862ddddddddddd0`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/LifecyclePolicies.html did you see this , looks like you can do cleanup through life cycle policies

Comment: I should manage deleting images explicitly using AWS CLI. Am not allowed to set lifecycle policy.

Comment: basically it's the URI for the untagged image. so that you can tag the untagged if needed